# DateTime format from database to input type='datetime' PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to retrieve one column from database with the type of **datetime** and pass to an input box type='datetime' in my form. But nothing is passed.

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="myDate">
<button id='getData'>Get</button>
```

script here

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#getData").on('click', function(){
            let foo = "foo";

            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "getData.php",
                data : {"foo" : foo},
                success: function(data){
                    $("#myDate").val(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

php file

```
<?php  
    require("conn.php");
    $res_ = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT date_ FROM table_info WHERE code = '1'");
    if($res_->num_rows>0){
        while($row = $res_->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row['date_'];
        }
    }

?>
```

I have noticed that the displayed value in the input box is mm/dd/yyyy --:-- -- and when it is saved in the database it has the milliseconds. I don't need the millisecond. Basically, I just want to save the date and time to the database then retrieve it and pass the exact value to the input box. But when I tried to retrieve it, nothing is displayed on the input box.

I also tried the

```
document.getElementById('myDate').value = data;
```

but still the same, nothing is diplayed.

Please help me on this one. Thank you.

Comment: `SEELECT`? Is that a typo just here in your question? Because that would explain an empty result...

Comment: There is no `datetime` input type

Comment: type [datetime was removed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime)... (I didn't knew it) So your input is a standard input. But that does not explain nothing showing... The typo in the SQL query is....

Comment: it was just a typo

Comment: already updated. and the type was 'datetime-local' rather than datetime. I don't have any issues saving it to database. I just can't display the value to the same input box.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1.You can change your field data type in database as datetime (Y-m-d) and change your input type datetime with the same format. So whenever you are saving and retrieving data, both has same format.

2.You can change date format when retrieving data as below:

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), '%m/%d%y') AS 'datedata'
```

Then you can use this date in your datetime input element.But please take a note, that when you are saving this date again in database, you need to change dateformat to timestamp again. Hope it helps you.

Comment: the type of column in the database is already datetime and the type of input box is 'datetime-local' but still not showing on the same input box.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your database of that column.